# Consulta MySQL complicada entre varias tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Saludos!

La Consulta se trata de usuarios, comentarios y la acción sobre los comentario (LIKE o DISLIKE). Trato, pero no se como hacer que retorne lo siguiente:

datos del comentario, datos del usuario, total de LIKE, total de DISLIKE, accion
accion: este será del usuario que haya iniciado sesión.

La estructura de las tablas son las siguientes:

**usuario:** id, etc...
**Comentario:** id, id_usuario, id_publicacion
**accion:** id, id_comentario, id_usuario, tipo (LIKE o DISLIKE)

He probado con las siguientes consultas parciales que si funcionan:

```
SELECT * FROM comentario INNER JOIN usuario ON comentario.id_usuario = usuario.id WHERE comentario.id_publicacion = XXXXX
SELECT COUNT(*), tipo FROM accion WHERE id_comentario = XXXXX GROUP BY tipo
```

No soy muy bueno con SQL, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Saludos**

Yo en lo personal usare para mi sugerencias subconsultas; partiendo que tabla `comentario` como raiz:

```
SELECT ccm.*, CONTEOS.SONLIKES, CONTEOS.SONDISLIKES, USR.*
FROM comentario  ccm
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID_COMENTARIO, ID_USUARIO, SUM(IIF(TIPO='LIKE', 1,0)) SONLIKES,
         SUM(IIF(TIPO='DISLIKE', 1,0)) SONDISLIKES
    FROM ACCION
    GROUP BY ID_COMENTARIO, ID_USUARIO
) CONTEOS ON CONTEOS.ID_COMENTARIO=CCM.ID AND CONTEOS.ID_USUARIO=CCM.ID_USUARIO
INNER JOIN USUARIO USR ON USR.ID=CCM.ID_USUARIO
```

A lo anterior debes agregar condicional para filtrar solo los datos del usuario en sesión.

> Lo que puse como `TIPO='LIKE'` y `TIPO='DISLIKE'` adecualo para poner la forma en que se identifica cuando es LIKE y cuando DISLIKE; según corresponda de forma correcta (si es número, letra, cadena, ....)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, probé el SQL y funciona efectivamente. Sin embargo se ejecuta sobre comentarios que solamente tienen LIKE o DISLIKE, también en la parte de sumar, la subconsulta agrupa los like-dislike por comentario y usuario, es decir que siempre va a contar 1, ya que un usuario solo puede realizar esa acción sobre un comentario una vez (a nivel de registro)... Yo he realizado la siguientes modificaciones:

Comment: SELECT ccm.*, IFNULL(CONTEOS.SONLIKES, 0), IFNULL(CONTEOS.SONDISLIKES,0), USR.*
FROM comentario ccm
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT id_comentario, id_usuario, SUM(IF(status='LIKE', 1,0)) SONLIKES,
         SUM(IF(status='DISLIKE', 1,0)) SONDISLIKES
    FROM like_comentario
    GROUP BY id_comentario
) CONTEOS ON CONTEOS.id_comentario = CCM.id AND CONTEOS.id_usuario = CCM.id_usuario
INNER JOIN usuario USR ON USR.id = CCM.id_usuario WHERE ccm.id_publicacion = 18 ORDER BY ccm.fecha_registro ASC

Comment: Al parecer creo que funciona bien (me gustaría su sugerencia), pero me estaría faltando una columna adicional que diga si el usuario con ID constante XXXX (recibe como parámetro) ha ralizado LIKE o DISLIKE sobre ese comentario en cuestión.